ImportError when importing KServe library
I'm trying to import the KServe module, but the import statement is throwing:
ImportError: cannot import name 'RootModel' from 'pydantic' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)`.

I'm using the sample provided from the KServe docs. The issue persists after uninstalling and reinstalling the library. Is this issue due version conflicts? Should I be using some other version?
This is my code:
from kubernetes import client 
from kserve import KServeClient
from kserve import constants
from kserve import utils

It throws this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
      1 from kubernetes import client 
----> 2 from kserve import KServeClient
      3 from kserve import constants
      4 from kserve import utils

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/__init__.py:18
     15 from __future__ import absolute_import
     17 from .model import Model
---> 18 from .model_server import ModelServer
     19 from .inference_client import InferenceServerClient
     20 from .protocol.infer_type import InferRequest, InferInput, InferResponse, InferOutput

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/model_server.py:33
     31 from .model import BaseKServeModel
     32 from .model_repository import ModelRepository
---> 33 from .protocol.dataplane import DataPlane
     34 from .protocol.grpc.server import GRPCServer
     35 from .protocol.model_repository_extension import ModelRepositoryExtension

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/protocol/dataplane.py:33
     31 from ..utils.utils import create_response_cloudevent, is_structured_cloudevent
     32 from .infer_type import InferRequest, InferResponse
---> 33 from .rest.openai import OpenAIModel
     35 JSON_HEADERS = [
     36     "application/json",
     37     "application/cloudevents+json",
     38     "application/ld+json",
     39 ]
     41 # RayServeHandle used to be the return type of serve.run.
     42 # RayServeSyncHandle has been the return type of serve.run since Ray 2.5.
     43 # DeploymentHandle will be the new return type (still under feature flag in Ray 2.7).
     44 # ref https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/37817
     45 # On Ray 2.10, it now returns DeploymentHandle:
     46 # https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/serve/api/index.html#deployment-handles

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/protocol/rest/openai/__init__.py:15
      1 # Copyright 2023 The KServe Authors.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
---> 15 from .openai_model import (
     16     ChatPrompt,
     17     CompletionRequest,
     18     ChatCompletionRequest,
     19     OpenAIModel,
     20 )
     22 from .openai_proxy_model import OpenAIProxyModel
     23 from .openai_chat_adapter_model import OpenAIChatAdapterModel

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/protocol/rest/openai/openai_model.py:21
     17 import inspect
     19 from pydantic import BaseModel
---> 21 from kserve.protocol.rest.openai.types import (
     22     ChatCompletion,
     23     ChatCompletionChunk,
     24     Completion,
     25     CreateChatCompletionRequest,
     26     CreateCompletionRequest,
     27 )
     29 from ....model import BaseKServeModel
     32 class ChatPrompt(BaseModel):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/protocol/rest/openai/types/__init__.py:17
      1 # Copyright 2023 The KServe Authors.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
     15 from typing import Union
---> 17 from kserve.protocol.rest.openai.types.openapi import (
     18     ChatCompletionRequestAssistantMessage,
     19     ChatCompletionRequestFunctionMessage,
     20     ChatCompletionRequestSystemMessage,
     21     ChatCompletionRequestToolMessage,
     22     ChatCompletionRequestUserMessage,
     23     ChatCompletionResponseMessage,
     24 )
     25 from kserve.protocol.rest.openai.types.openapi import (
     26     ChatCompletionStreamResponseDelta as ChoiceDelta,
     27 )
     28 from kserve.protocol.rest.openai.types.openapi import ChatCompletionTokenLogprob

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kserve/protocol/rest/openai/types/openapi.py:23
     19 from __future__ import annotations
     21 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Union
---> 23 from pydantic import (
     24     AnyUrl,
     25     BaseModel,
     26     ConfigDict,
     27     Field,
     28     PositiveFloat,
     29     RootModel,
     30     confloat,
     31     conint,
     32     constr,
     33 )
     34 from typing_extensions import Literal
     37 class Error(BaseModel):

ImportError: cannot import name 'RootModel' from 'pydantic' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

My pydantic and KServe versions are as below :
Name: pydantic
Version: 1.10.18
Summary: Data validation and settings management using python type hints
Home-page: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic
Author: Samuel Colvin
Author-email: s@muelcolvin.com
License: MIT
Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by: dataproc_jupyter_plugin, fastapi, google-cloud-aiplatform, kserve, ydata-profiling
---
Name: kserve
Version: 0.13.1
Summary: KServe Python SDK
Home-page: https://github.com/kserve/kserve/tree/master/python/kserve
Author: The KServe Authors
Author-email: dsun20@bloomberg.net
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: cloudevents, fastapi, grpcio, httpx, kubernetes, numpy, orjson, pandas, prometheus-client, protobuf, psutil, pydantic, python-dateutil, pyyaml, ray, six, tabulate, timing-asgi, uvicorn
Required-by: 

